# How to split a string which contains multiple key value pairs

Tags: java, regex, string-matching

I have a string:

```
Single line : Some text
Multi1: multi (Va1)    Multi2 : multi (Va2) Multi3 : multi (Val3)
Dots....20/12/2013 (EOY)
```

and I am trying to retrieve all the key value pairs. My first attempt

(Single line|Multi[0-9]{1}|Dots)( *:? *[.]* *| *:? *)(.*)

seems to work but does not handle multiple key value pairs on one line. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "Single line : Some text\n"
             + "Multi1: multi (Va1)    Multi2 : multi (Va2) "
             + "Multi3 : multi (Val3)\n"
             + "Dots....20/12/2013 (EOY)";

    String wd = "[^\\s.:]+(?:[^\\S\\n]+[^\\s.:]+)*";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<key>" + wd + ")"
                              + "\\s*(?::|\\.+)\\s*"
                              + "(?<value>" + wd + "(?:\\s*\\([^)]+\\))?)"
                              + "(?!\\s*:)(?=\\s|$)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group("key")+"->"+m.group("value"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String text = "Single line : Some text\r\n" + 
"Multi1: multi (Va1)    Multi2 : multi (Va2) Multi3 : multi (Val3)\r\n" +
"Dots....20/12/2013 (EOY)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\p{Alnum}[\\p{Alnum}\\s/]+?)\\s?(:|\\.+)\\s?(\\p{Alnum}[\\p{Alnum}\\s/]+?)(?=($|\\()|(\\s\\())", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + "-->" + matcher.group(3));
}
```

Output:

```
Single line-->Some text
Multi1-->multi 
Multi2-->multi 
Multi3-->multi 
Dots-->20/12/2013
```

Explanation:

- I am limiting the keys and values to "starts with alphanumeric",
  "contains any number of alphanumerics, spaces or slashes".
- I am limiting the separator to "optional space, :, optional space" or
  "optional space, any number of consecutive dots, optional space".
- I am using groups 1 and 3 to define the key and value in the
  `Pattern`.
- Group 2 is used to provide alternate separators as above.
- Finally, the `Pattern` is delimited at the end, either with a new
  line, or with an open round bracket, or, with a space followed by an
  open round bracket.

Note that you can't use quantifiers in a lookahead or lookbehind group, hence the repetition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall the exact syntax, but I think it's something like this:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
  String match = matcher.group();
}
```

The goal here is that you need to iterate over the current line and tell it "while you are still finding stuff, return to me the string on this line that matched." Since you have multiple matches on the same line, it should keep pulling out findings for you. [Here is the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) for Matcher as a reference.

This is sadly another reason why Java is really not well-suited for this sort of thing, and before anyone downmods me understand I say that as a criticism of the Java APIs here, not the language.

Comment: I am aware of the syntax but the regex is treating everything after the first semicolon for line2 as the value and not splitting it.